# Ограничение перемещения объекта по оси X

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код:

```
// Скорость
public Vector2 speed = new Vector2(10, 10);
// Направление
public Vector2 direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);

private Vector2 movement;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    movement = new Vector2(
        speed.x * direction.x,
        speed.y * direction.y); 
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    // Применить движение к rigidbody
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = movement;
}
```

Как сделать ограничение перемещения? Чтобы объект перемещался, скажем, на единицу влево и останавливался.
Заранее Спасибо).

P.S. Новичок в C# под Unity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[SerializeField] 
Vector2 _speed = new Vector2(10, 10); 

[SerializeField]
Vector2 _direction = new Vector2(-1, 0);

// Зададим максимальную дистанцию.
[SerializeField]
float _maxDistance = 1f;

Vector2 _movement;
Vector2 _origin;
Vector2 _destination;
bool _done;

// Перенесем расчет velocity из Update в Awake, так как нет смысла считать 
// одно и то же на каждом кадре.
void Awake () 
{
    // Вычислим скорость.
    _movement = new Vector2(_speed.x * _direction.x, _speed.y * _direction.y); 

    // Сохраним начальную позицию.
    _origin = transform.position; 

    // Вычислим целевую позицию.
    _destination = _direction.normalized * _maxDistance; 

    // Зададим velocity.
    GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = _movement; 
}

void Update()
{
    // Если уже закончили, то ничего не делаем.
    if(_done) 
        return;

    // Получим расстояние между стартовой и текущей позицией.
    var distance = Mathf.Abs(Vector2.Distance(_origin, transform.position));

    // Если объект уже ушел достаточно далеко.
    if(distance >= _maxDistance)
    {
        // Не даем объекту уйти за _maxDistance.
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(_origin, _destination, distance);

        // Обнуляем скорость.
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = Vector2.zero;

        // Устанавливаем флаг завершения.
        _done = true;
    }
}
```

P.S. Хочу обратить внимание, что и установка `transform.position` и даже установка `velocity` вручную могут нарушить физическую симуляцию. Потому нужно пробовать, подходит ли это для Ваших целей. В общем случае, для работы с физикой лучше использовать `AddForce` и ограничивать движение коллайдерами, а без физики - лучше вручную двигать объект через cвойства и методы `transform` без использования rigidbody вообще.